# Convert radian to degree in flutter expression

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have an input expression from user, and there might be `sin()`, `cos()` and `tan()` in it, and also multi dimensional functions like `sin(60 + cos(30))`.

I am using math_expression to evaluate the expression, but this package uses radian instead of degree. What should I do i f want to user degrees instead of radian?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Conversion_between_radians_and_degrees

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

1 rad = 180°/π
1 deg = (1 rad * π)/180

https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/radians-to-degrees.html

Comment: I know how to convert radian to degree, I want to parse the string so that radian converts to degree.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex function to convert the user's input before the operation:

```
String replaceTrigFunctionsWithTransformation(String input) {
    final RegExp trigFunctionRegex = RegExp(r'(sin|cos|tan)\(([^)]+)\)');

    String result = input;
    for (Match match in trigFunctionRegex.allMatches(input)) {
      final originalMatch = match.group(0); // e.g., sin(45)
      final trigFunction = match.group(1); // e.g., sin
      final innerExpression = match.group(2); // e.g., 45

      if (originalMatch != null &&
          trigFunction != null &&
          innerExpression != null) {
        // Replace sin(45) with sin((pi/180)*(45))
        final transformedExpression =
            '$trigFunction((π/180)*(${innerExpression.trim()}))';
        result = result.replaceFirst(originalMatch, transformedExpression);
      }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
void handleEqual() {
    if (currentInput.isEmpty) return;

    currentInput = replaceTrigFunctionsWithTransformation(currentInput);
}
```